# How can I stop the very frequent beachballs I have on my 2010 MacBook Pro, which has 8 GB RAM?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, performance

Beachballs happen every five minutes or so, taking about 15-30 seconds to resolve. I almost never had them before a few weeks ago.

Update: Just now, for the first time, the Mac was unresponsive for about 30 seconds when I physically opened it to bring it out of sleep. The screen was black. I pressed various keys with no effect.

Console output:

```
2/23/14Sunday 2:34:34.047 PM configd[17]: network changed: DNS* Proxy
2/23/14Sunday 2:34:34.050 PM SophosSXLD[78]: no DNS addresses found
2/23/14Sunday 2:34:34.051 PM UserEventAgent[355]: Captive: [CNInfoNetworkActive:1655] en1: SSID 'CenturyLink8979' making interface primary (cache indicates network not captive)
2/23/14Sunday 2:34:34.051 PM UserEventAgent[355]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en1: Evaluating
2/23/14Sunday 2:34:34.056 PM UserEventAgent[355]: Captive: en1: Not probing 'CenturyLink8979' (cache indicates not captive)
2/23/14Sunday 2:34:34.057 PM UserEventAgent[355]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en1: Authenticated
2/23/14Sunday 2:34:34.059 PM configd[17]: network changed: v4(en1!:192.168.0.3) DNS+ Proxy+ SMB
2/23/14Sunday 2:34:34.128 PM sandboxd[100]: ([75]) airportd(75) deny file-read-data /Library/Preferences/com.apple.security-common.plist
2/23/14Sunday 2:34:34.000 PM kernel[0]: flow_divert_kctl_disconnect (0): disconnecting group 1
2/23/14Sunday 2:34:36.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to 28:28:5d:2e:db:31
2/23/14Sunday 2:34:36.796 PM airportd[75]: _doAutoJoin: Already associated to “CenturyLink8979”. Bailing on auto-join.
2/23/14Sunday 2:34:37.119 PM apsd[201]: Failed to evaluate trust: No error. (0), result=5; retrying with revocation checking optional
2/23/14Sunday 2:34:37.165 PM apsd[201]: Unrecognized leaf certificate
2/23/14Sunday 2:34:38.415 PM parentalcontrolsd[11608]: StartObservingFSEvents [849:] -- *** StartObservingFSEvents started event stream
2/23/14Sunday 2:34:39.447 PM loginwindow[55]: CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.
2/23/14Sunday 2:38:02.000 PM kernel[0]: disk0s2: I/O error.
2/23/14Sunday 2:38:02.939 PM SophosWebD[77]: <SMENode: 0x7f888b8284c0> remoteNode csc:1ERROR! encountered an error while writing to outputstream| error:Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=32 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Broken pipe"
2/23/14Sunday 2:38:02.992 PM SophosWebD[77]: <SMENode: 0x7f888b84fd10> remoteNode csc:1ERROR! encountered an error while writing to outputstream| error:Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=32 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Broken pipe"
2/23/14Sunday 2:38:03.026 PM SophosWebD[77]: <SMENode: 0x7f888b8389f0> remoteNode csc:1ERROR! encountered an error while writing to outputstream| error:Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=32 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Broken pipe"
2/23/14Sunday 2:38:03.046 PM SophosWebD[77]: <SMENode: 0x7f888b853860> remoteNode csc:1ERROR! encountered an error while writing to outputstream| error:Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=32 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Broken pipe"
2/23/14Sunday 2:38:53.000 PM kernel[0]: disk0s2: I/O error.
2/23/14Sunday 2:38:53.000 PM kernel[0]: disk0s2: I/O error.
2/23/14Sunday 2:38:53.000 PM kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=11616[GoogleSoftwareUp] final status 0x0, allow (remove VALID)ing page
2/23/14Sunday 2:39:34.000 PM kernel[0]: disk0s2: I/O error.
2/23/14Sunday 2:40:15.000 PM kernel[0]: disk0s2: I/O error.
2/23/14Sunday 2:40:15.000 PM kernel[0]: disk0s2: I/O error.
2/23/14Sunday 2:43:19.395 PM ntpd[122]: FREQ state ignoring +0.002828 s
2/23/14Sunday 2:52:22.544 PM ntpd[122]: FREQ state ignoring +0.001693 s
2/23/14Sunday 2:52:35.004 PM firefox[2260]: CGSNewCIFilterByName
2/23/14Sunday 2:52:35.004 PM WindowServer[118]: CGXSetCIFilterValues: Invalid filter 0
2/23/14Sunday 2:52:35.005 PM WindowServer[118]: CGXSetWindowFilter: Invalid filter 0
2/23/14Sunday 2:52:46.899 PM firefox[2260]: CGSNewCIFilterByName
2/23/14Sunday 2:52:46.899 PM WindowServer[118]: CGXSetCIFilterValues: Invalid filter 0
2/23/14Sunday 2:52:46.899 PM WindowServer[118]: CGXSetWindowFilter: Invalid filter 0
2/23/14Sunday 2:52:49.184 PM firefox[2260]: CGSNewCIFilterByName
2/23/14Sunday 2:52:49.184 PM WindowServer[118]: CGXSetCIFilterValues: Invalid filter 0
2/23/14Sunday 2:52:49.184 PM WindowServer[118]: CGXSetWindowFilter: Invalid filter 0
2/23/14Sunday 2:52:57.967 PM firefox[2260]: CGSNewCIFilterByName
2/23/14Sunday 2:52:57.967 PM WindowServer[118]: CGXSetCIFilterValues: Invalid filter 0
2/23/14Sunday 2:52:57.967 PM WindowServer[118]: CGXSetWindowFilter: Invalid filter 0
2/23/14Sunday 3:03:45.319 PM Console[11654]: setPresentationOptions called with NSApplicationPresentationFullScreen when there is no visible fullscreen window; this call will be ignored.
2/23/14Sunday 3:03:50.040 PM WindowServer[118]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "Console" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
2/23/14Sunday 3:03:52.487 PM WindowServer[118]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Console" after 3.45 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
```

Disk Utility shows the following:

```
Verifying and repairing partition map for “Hitachi HTS545025B9SA02 Media”
Checking prerequisites
Checking the partition list
Adjusting partition map to fit whole disk as required
Checking for an EFI system partition
Checking the EFI system partition’s size
Checking the EFI system partition’s file system
Checking all HFS data partition loader spacesChecking booter partitions
Checking booter partition disk0s3
Checking file systemChecking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
Checking extents overflow file.
Checking catalog file.
Checking multi-linked files.
Checking catalog hierarchy.
Checking extended attributes file.
Checking volume bitmap.
Checking volume information.
The volume Recovery HD appears to be OK.
Volume repair complete.
Updating boot support partitions for the volume as required.
Reviewing boot support loaders
Checking Core Storage Physical Volume partitions
Updating Windows boot.ini files as required
The partition map appears to be OK
```

Comment: If you would publish like 20-30 lines of your Console so we can take a look, please

Comment: Do you have time machine making backups since before the slowness started?

Comment: Thanks bmike--when I went to Time Machine, it was not set up and its switch was set to off. I'm trying to set it up now. It says "No configured AirPort base stations have been found."

Comment: Time Machine would be easiest to enable if you have a USB hard drive you could plug in. It needs to be formatted for Mac, so if you insert a PC drive, it will get erased if you select it for Time Machine - so read the warnings carefully if you don't have a blank drive handy to start Time Machine.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the IO errors, you need to back up any important files immediately, starting with the most important first. Once that's done, you'll want to run Disk Utility to see if the drive can be erased and get a clean start or if you need to have the hardware serviced.

Also, when the kernel logs an IO error, my experience is you almost certainly have a hardware problem or at best a software corruption that an erase and reinstall of the OS should alert you if the IO errors go away after a wipe. Keep in mind, with bad data on storage, you can't always trust the logs or even Disk Utility to self-repair things and might need another computer to repair/diagnose things.

Comment: Thanks. I just ran Repair Disk and it seemed to say everything was fine. I posted the results.

Comment: Repair Disk will check the structural integrity of the filesystem's internals, checking inodes and pointers and other such complicated stuff. It will not read each file end to end to seek corruption or media failure at an individual file level. It seems you have a a dead bit of disk that doesn't realise it's dead, and is not detectable at an FS level. I would be backing up, likely more will follow.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem... disk0s2: I/O error.

I had this on my iMac. Disk repairs and a reformat of the disk cleaned me up for a few weeks, but with in 2 months of getting this error, my hard disk was dead and would no longer boot.

Dead disk was confirmed and replaced at the Apple store.

Comment: Thanks. What was the cost at the Apple store? Did you price out any other options?

Comment: Sorry. I had Apple Care. I believe they said it would have been between $2-300, but I realize that is a big span and not very helpful.

Comment: That is helpful, thanks. Just to update, the Mac seems to work OK if I only have a browser, and no other applications, open, and as long as there are only three or four tabs open. But this wasn't previously the case, and as I said there are 8 GB RAM. Does this parallel your experience?

Answer (score 0):

You have few disk I/O problems showing (not a good news), so do the disk repair with the Disk Utility locate in your utility folder.

Also your Firefox and your Google are having some problems.
Make sure they are updated.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by Google? Chrome?

Comment: Yes Chrome, but it is not so Important, you are having more serious problem with your disk. Hope you use backup if not do it before it is to late.

Comment: Thanks. I just ran Repair Disk and it seemed to say everything was fine. I posted the results.

Comment: Do you have more than one disk showing?

Comment: There's "250.06 GB Hitachi HTS5...." In a sub-menu beneath it there's "Macintosh HD." Next down, "SuperDrive." Next, after a divider, "decryptedFile.dmg," under which, in a sub-menu, is "Flash Player."

Comment: ok you 2 disks, check the Macintosh HD

Comment: For your information: I started to get the beach-ball (for very short periods), I stopped using Chrome, and the associated culprit the Google Chrome Helper (which is the one doing it). The beach-ball did not show since.

Comment: Verifying volume “Macintosh HD”Checking file systemPerforming live verification.Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.Checking extents overflow file.Checking catalog file.Checking multi-linked files.Checking catalog hierarchy.Checking extended attributes file.Checking volume bitmap.Checking volume information.The volume Macintosh HD appears to be OK.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about Chrome, but I haven't used it in days. Did you uninstall it?

Comment: No need to uninstall, just do not use the Chrome as browser. Back to your problem, since the Disk Utility did not find a permanent disk error-- please run the Console again and type the Disk in the filtering (search window), now you should see only disk messages, so publish those to see who is initiating them.

Answer (score -1):

I hate to say this, but get a new HDD (An SSD if you can afford one).